# About twin paradox

Tags: special-relativity

It is not actually a twin paradox but I have no idea what to call it. So let's assume that there are two person named Alvin and Jack. Alvin drive a spaceship at the speed of 0.6c where Jack is standing still on earth. At the instant Alvin and Jack pass each other, they start their watch. When Jack measure time at 5 seconds, Alvin will measure time at 5*(1-0.6^2)^0.5 = 4 seconds. This happen when we use Jack as a reference. On the other hand, if we use Alvin as reference, Jack will be moving away from Alvin at 0.6c. So when Alvin measure time at 4 seconds, Jack should measure time as 4*(1-0.6^2)^0.5 = 3.2 seconds

So when Alvin is at 4 seconds, what is Jack's time?

Comment: I mean Jack's time is either 5 seconds or 3.2 seconds so which one is it?

Comment: For the record this is not my homework but a passage from young physics. I just don't get the meaning of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bear in mind that you have 2 different reference frame. Let's call $S$ to Jack's frame (on Earth) ans $S'$ to the Alvin's frame (on the ship).

From $S$ you see that 5 seconds on Earth passes when 4 seconds passes for the ship (and viceversa in $S$).
But, from $S'$, you see that 4 seconds for the ship means 3.2 seconds on Earth.

The key point here is that you have two frames, you can't use an universal frame. The equivalence of time between Jack and Alvin is determined by the frame you are using. As a note, remember that two simultaneous events are (in general) not simultaneous if you change your frame [See for example the [pole-barn Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ladder_paradox)].

As an exercise, you can try to find a frame $S_\alpha$ where 1 second on Earth is equivalent to $\alpha$ seconds on the ship.

Answer (score -1):

Since Alvin is in a spaceship he will of course be moving faster then Jack standing on Earth. Time does affect things with gravity and speed so Alvin watch would be going slower because the faster you go the slower time will pass for you. [Explanation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FflcA85zcOM)

Comment: The phrase *"he will [...] be moving faster then Jack standing on Earth"* misses the point. Velocity is relative, both participants observe time-dilation on the part of the other.